# Simple case statement is failing in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I had written a very simple case statement which is failing. I double checked the syntax but could not find what went wrong. Can somebody please let me know?

```
#!/bin/bash

opt_type=0


function opt_type
{
        echo "Opt Porvisioning tool starting..."

        echo -e "1. ABC \n2. DEF \n3. HIJ \n"
        read opt_input

        case $opt_input in
        1|abc|ABC)
                opt_type=1;

        2|def|DEF)    
                opt_type=2;

        3|hij|HIJ)    
                opt_type=3;

        4|exit|Exit) echo "Exiting ..."

        *) echo "Please enter a valid entry. Exiting!!"

        esac
}

echo $opt_type


./opt_type.sh: line 16: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
./opt_type.sh: line 16: `       2|def|DEF)
-bash-3.2$
```

I don't see any such symbol (`) then why is it complaining?

Comment: Aside from the lack of ;; terminators, did you expect "1." to match `1|abc|ABC)`? It won't.

Comment: I dint try to match "1." but just out of curiosity I want to see if I can do that by using a backslash (escape character) or if there is any other way to match "1."?

Comment: Just `1.|abc|ABC)` should do it, you don't need to escape '.' since it's not special to the case statement. It's not a regex, it uses file metacharacters. By the way, if your data might look like "AbC", you can allow for that with: `1.|[aA][bB][cC])` (ugly, but effective for short strings at least).

Answer (score 1):

You must close each cases by `;;` not `;` =)

So :

```
#!/bin/bash

opt_type=0


function opt_type
{
        echo "Opt Porvisioning tool starting..."

        echo -e "1. ABC \n2. DEF \n3. HIJ \n"
        read opt_input

        case $opt_input in
        1|abc|ABC)
                opt_type=1
        ;;
        2|def|DEF)    
                opt_type=2
        ;;
        3|hij|HIJ)    
                opt_type=3
        ;;
        4|exit|Exit) echo "Exiting ..."
        ;;
        *) echo "Please enter a valid entry. Exiting!!"
        ;;
        esac
}

echo $opt_type
```

Answer (score 1):

You should double semicolons:

```
case $opt_input in
    1|abc|ABC)
        opt_type=1;;
    2|def|DEF)    
        opt_type=2;;
    3|hij|HIJ)    
        opt_type=3;;
    4|exit|Exit)
        echo "Exiting ...";;
    *)
        echo "Please enter a valid entry. Exiting!!";;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

In Bash you need two semicolons after each case in your case statement.  I also took the case statement out of the function, since the function was never called.  The following works as expected

```
#!/bin/bash
opt_type=0
echo "Opt Porvisioning tool starting..."
echo -e "1. ABC \n2. DEF \n3. HIJ \n"
read opt_input
case $opt_input in
    1|abc|ABC) opt_type=1;;
    2|def|DEF) opt_type=2;;
    3|hij|HIJ) opt_type=3;;
    4|exit|Exit) echo "Exiting ...";;
    *) echo "Please enter a valid entry. Exiting!!";;
esac
echo $opt_type
```